# Multithreaded Server in LInux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, pthreads

I am Working on server Programming in C in Linux environment.At same time there might be several clients linked with the Server.It's my first project on server Programming and not having much experience in Multi-threading.Till Now i have Programmed following for Multithreading.

I want to get some idea about following Points.

1.How many clients will the server Handle?

2.will `pthread_t thr;`create multiple Threads or i need to do something like `pthread_t thr[X]` to create X Threads ?

3.How can i get the data for each client in the following code ?

4.Will `pthread_create` create a new copy of `*connection_handler` for each new client connected.

```
void dieWithError(char *errormsg);

FILE *file;


void *connection_handler(void *socket_desc)
{
    //Get the socket descriptor
    int sock = *(int*)socket_desc;
    int read_size;
    char *message , client_message[2000];



    //Receive a message from client
    while( (read_size = recv(sock , client_message , 2000 , 0)) > 0 )
    {
        //end of string marker
        client_message[read_size] = '\0';

           printf("%s",client_message); 
           fprintf(file,"%s", client_message);


        //clear the message buffer
        memset(client_message, 0, 2000);
    }

    if(read_size == 0)
    {
        puts("Client disconnected");
        fflush(stdout);
    }
    else if(read_size == -1)
    {
        perror("recv failed");
    }

    return 0;
} 




int main(int argc, char** argv) {

    int sock_desc = 0, connfd = 0,listenfd =0;
    struct sockaddr_in serv_addr;
    int clntSock; 
    struct sockaddr_in echoClntAddr; 
    unsigned int clntLen; 
    char sendBuff[1025];
    char recvBuff[10025];
    int n = 0;
    pthread_t thr;



    sock_desc = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0); 

    if(sock_desc < 0 )
       dieWithError("Unable to open Socket\n");  

    memset(&serv_addr,0,sizeof(serv_addr)); 

    serv_addr.sin_family = AF_INET ;
    serv_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serv_addr.sin_port = htons(7024);

    if(bind(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&serv_addr, sizeof(serv_addr)) < 0) 
       dieWithError("bind failed\n");

    if(listen(sock_desc,3) < 0)
       dieWithError("listen failed\n");  

     file = fopen("testServer.txt", "w");


      clntSock = sizeof(struct sockaddr);
      int i =0;
      while((connfd = accept(sock_desc, (struct sockaddr *)&echoClntAddr,(socklen_t*)&clntSock)))
    {
        puts("Connection accepted");



        if( pthread_create( &thr, NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &connfd) < 0)
        {
            perror("could not create thread");
            return 1;
        }

        //Now join the thread , so that we dont terminate before the thread
        //pthread_join( thread_id , NULL);
        puts("Handler assigned");
    }

    if (connfd < 0)
    {
        perror("accept failed");
        return 1;
    }

       return (EXIT_SUCCESS);
}

void dieWithError(char *errormsg){
     printf("%s", errormsg);


}
```

Comment: You have a logical error that will manifest itself if two clients connect at the same time... You have no control over when the thread actually starts to run, which means you could have this situation: 1. First thread created, but it doesn't start to run. 2. You call `accept` on the second connection, and create it's thread. 3. The *second* thread starts running first. 4. The first thread starts running. Now since you pass a pointer to the same variable to both threads, both thread will then use the same socket.

Comment: ok u mean that both will use the same Port and will not transfer the connection to ephemeral port.

Comment: No there will still be two different connections, but there is a chance (small, but still a chance) that two or more threads gets the same socket. It will work for small and simple test cases, but you can't pass a pointer to a single variable in real production code when you expect multiple simultaneous connections.

Comment: Is Asynchronous Socket Programming posible in C

Comment: Of course, you have it, it's just a little flawed. In a real big production server code, the thread probably needs more data passed to it, and then you need to have a structure with the data, that you allocate dynamically and therefore work around this specific flaw.

Answer (score 1):

1. It depends on the server machine, and how many threads it can handle. Generally speaking, the more threads you have, the more time the operating system will spend just switching between threads meaning the threads themselves will have less time doing any real work.
2. E.g. `pthread_t thr;` is a single variable, able to hold a single thread. You *can* reuse it for multiple threads, but then you loose the other threads leading to a resource leak. You probably need an array or a list if you want multiple threads.
3. Structures. One structure per thread, each structure containing the thread information (`pthread_t`), the client socket, and everything else needed by both the main thread and the client-handling thread.
4. No. `connection_handler` is a *function*, there will only be one instance of a function per process in memory, functions are not copied.

Comment: pthread_t thr;
pthread_create( &thr, NULL ,  connection_handler , (void*) &connfd)

I am doing like this in my software and it handles multiple clients and displays the data from each client.

Comment: In connection_handler (point 4.) in Answer You mean that one single instance of connection_handler will be used by all the threads.

Comment: @JuniorBillgates There will only be one copy of the function code in memory, there will however be multiple thread contexts pointing to the same function.

Comment: @JuniorBillgates Regarding your first comment, reusing the `thr` variable like that means you will loose the previous thread when you call `pthread_create` again. The `thr` variable will only have information about the last thread you created.

Comment: As you Said "The thr variable will only have information about the last thread you created". But will it be able to receive data from all clients after i reuse the thr.

Comment: @JuniorBillgates Think of the case where you have two clients connected simultaneously, and therefore two threads. When the threads exit, how will you join the first thread? Do you detach the threads so you don't have to join them?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80025/discussion-between-junior-bill-gates-and-joachim-pileborg).